# Delete Indexed In RavenDB not found

Tags: ravendb

I am trying to write a generic delete function for  multi tenant ravendb for integration testing the class is -

```
public class RavenDeleteAll
{
    private readonly IDocumentStore _store;
    private readonly string _testDataBase;

    public RavenDeleteAll(string testDataBase, IDocumentStore store)
    {
        _testDataBase = testDataBase;
        _store = store;
    }

    public void Clear<T>(string indexName)
    {
        using (var session = _store.OpenSession(_testDataBase))
        {
            session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.DeleteIndex(indexName);

            session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.PutIndex(indexName, new IndexDefinitionBuilder<T>
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            Map = documents => documents.Select(entity => new { })
                                                                                        });
            var indexDefinition = session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.GetIndex(indexName);
            session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<T>(indexName)
           .WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()
           .Take(0)
           .ToList();

            session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.DeleteByIndex(indexName, new IndexQuery());


        }

    }
}
```

Note that in the code i try to read back the index after putindex call for sanity check. but when I execute the index it throws an invalidoperationexception stating that /indexes/UTO does not exist?

Also from management console I can clearly see the index - 
 [image]

What am I not doing? Also the index is created under default database and not the actual database name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are creating the index in the Default database not the Tenant Database then asking the Tenant Database for that Index. You need to create the index in the database where you are going to use it. The following is not tested but should work for creating the index in the tenant database.

```
IDatabaseCommands context = session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.ForDatabase(database);
context.PutIndex(indexName, new IndexDefinitionBuilder<T>
    {
        Map = documents => documents.Select(entity => new { })
    });
```

Comment: This worked like magic. Thanks sooooo much for saving me a late night. I would like to kiss you but that would be inappropriate. Five stars to this answer!!!!!